# A new convergence problem for the conditional expectation

Tags: conditional-probability, convergence, conditional-expectation, central-limit-theorem

You have risks $X_1$, $X_2$, ...

(they are assumed to be independent, but not necessarily identically distributed)

and

$S_n= X_1 + X_2 + \cdots +X_n$

QUESTION: under what reasonable conditions do we have that

$\mathbb{E}[Xi | S_n]$ converges to $\mathbb{E}[Xi]$?

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume that all the $X_i$ have finite mean and variance (not necessarily uniformly bounded at this point).

I claim it is necessary that $\mathrm{var}[S_n]\to\infty$, since otherwise the correlation between $X_i$ and $S_n$ doesn't go to zero.

This is not sufficient. Suppose all the $X_i$ take on only even values, except that $X_1$ is 0 or 1 with equal probability.  If we see $S_n$ is odd, we know $X_1$ is odd and therefore $X_1=1$. If we see $S_n$ is even we know $X_1$ is even and therefore 0. So it is not the case that $E[X_1|S_n]\to E[X_1]$. You could probably do other clever things taking $X_i$s to be 0 or a logarithm of a prime to get it to fail for more different $X_i$ at once.

I *think* the variance going to infinity is sufficient except when you're cheating like I was with the odd/even numbers.  That is, I think something like the following is true: the result holds if  you're allowed to add noise to stop any trickery.
If $\mathrm{var}[S_n]\to\infty$ then $E[\tilde X_i|S_n]\to E[\tilde X_i]$ for $\tilde X_i=X_i+\epsilon_i$ for any iid finite-variance absolutely continuous $\epsilon_i$

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  Can I ask why did you claim $var[S_n]\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Because if $\mathrm{var}[S_n]\to M<\infty$, $X_i$ contributes $\mathrm{var}[X_i]/M$ of the total variance, which isn't zero, and so the linear correlation between $X_i$ and $S_n$ isn't zero.

Comment: You have explained that "since otherwise the correlation between $X_i$ and $S_n$" does not go to zero". What is the intuitive or proof to say that if this happens then the convergence holds true? I want to have a clear understanding of your nice explanation.

Comment: Actually, you use this to say that the conditional expectation can become a non-conditional expectation because the correlation is zero, but if correlation equal to zero is equivalent to say that they are independent. For normal distribution, this is true but not for other distributions.

Comment: The intuition is that if the correlation goes to zero the projection of $X_i$ on to linear functions of $S_n$ is just $X_i$ and that's probably true for other sufficient smooth functions of $S_n$, but sufficiently detailed functions of $S_n$ can extract detailed embedded information about $X_i$. So we need to stop you using 'sufficiently detailed' functions of $S_n$.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the Normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you want to advise me on a book or resource for covering such a thing, what would you say?

Comment: you may want to have a look at my new claim:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/567342/a-problem-in-convergence-and-limit