# A problem in convergence and limit

Tags: probability, convergence, conditional-expectation, central-limit-theorem

For any non-negative integer $n$ and some finite $r$, we introduce the notation $n_k$ which indicates the number of $\{X_1, X_2, \cdots , X_n\}$ belonging to the $k$-th distribution type, for $k=1, 2, \cdots, r$. Here, it is assumed that $X_i$'s are independent, and that $E[X_i|S_n]$ converges to $E[X_i]$, for $i=1, 2, \cdots, n$. Then, the following condition holds true.

There are at most $r$ different elements in the set of all distributions of the sequence $X_1, X_2, \cdots,$. Moreover, we have that

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \min_{1\leq k\leq r} \frac{n_k}{ln \sigma[S_n]} = \infty,
\end{equation}
and for $i$ given, there exists an $n\geq i$ such that

\begin{equation}
\sup_x \bar{f}_{S_{n/i}}(x) < \infty
\end{equation}
where $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ and $S_{n/i} = S_n - X_i$, for $i=1, 2, \cdots , n$, and $\bar{f}_{S_{n/i}}(x)$ is the probability density function of the normalized version of $S_{n/i}$, i.e., $\frac{S_{n/i} - E[S_{n/i}]}{\sigma[S_{n/i}]}$ with expectation and standard deviation $E[S_{n/i}]$ and $\sigma[S_{n/i}]$, respectively.

My question is: Why $r$ should be a finite number, what if r is infinite (the number of different distributions goes to infinity)? Can we provide another condition that satisfies the above condition?

Comment: When $r$ is infinite you can't even get started, because then potentially each $X_i$ has its own distribution.

Comment: So, what happens if we say each $X_i$ has its own distribution. I mean, can we state something similar\equivalent to the above condition in case each $X_i$ has different distributions?

Comment: It's impossible to say, because you haven't asserted anything: you have only listed a bunch of assumptions.

Comment: I mean suppose that we have a sequence of independent, but not essentially identical distribution of $X_1$, $X_2, \cdots$. Then if it is possible to state a condition like above to make sure that $E[X_i| S_n]$ converges to $E[X_i]$?

Answer (score 0):

$r$ need not be finite. Assuming your result is correct, it is sufficient that  the condition on the $n_k$ holds for all $r$.

Proof by taking subsequences. Let $i$ and $r<\infty$ be given. Fix a set of $r$ distribution types including the type of $X_i$, and take the subsequence consisting only of those types.  Write $\tilde S_n$ for the subsequence partial sums.  Your condition on $n_k$ still applies to the subsequence (the numerator is the same and the denominator becomes smaller).

Your result thus says $E[X_i|\tilde S_n]\to E[X_i]$.  But the full sequence partial sums $S_n$ cannot contain any more information about $X_i$ than $\tilde S_n$ do, because they are a function of $\tilde S_n$ and variables independent of the subsequence.

It does seem necessary that each type appears infinitely often, and there's still a gap between that and your condition, potentially allowing for more refinement.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "each type appears infinitely often", you mean all $X_i$ has its own distribution?

Comment: No, I mean there are infinitely many different types and for each type there are infinitely many $X_i$ of that type.   Having every $X_i$ be a different type would contradict the assumption about $n_k$.